# Identify common rows based on a column value and adding conditions for the grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I am stuck with an SQL issue. Could you please help me with the following:
I currently have an SQL which retrieves data based on various tables and concatenated values.
I have to limit the data selected by checking if part of the concatenated values are the same and do a calculation to determine if this group of records should be displayed or not.

Example of data:

```
ID  Acct ID    Credit  Debit  Balance
1   10.1.2.3      -10      0       10
2   10.5.2.4        0     10       10
3   22.6.1.1        0    -15      -15
4   11.3.5.5       -5      0       -5
5   12.3.5.6       -2      0       -2
6   15.1.1.1       30      0       30
7   20.16.5.1       0      7        7
```

The part of the concatenated to take into consideration is the 3rd value. (Delimiter used: ".")

1. For ID 1 and 2, the 3rd value of the concatenated field is "2", which meets the first criteria.

Then for the two lines of records the credit and debit amount sums up to zero, which meets the second criteria. Hence ID 1 and 2 should not be displayed.

2. Same for ID 4, 5 and 7, the 3rd concatenated value is the same, that is, "5", the credit and debit amounts sum up to zero. They should not be selected in the SQL query.
3. ID 3 and 6 have the same 3rd concatenated value but the sum is not zero, hence these two lines should be displayed.

Could you please help me with the above? Please note that I already know how to retrieve only the 3rd value of the concatenated field.

Thank you very much in advance.

Reply:
Hello thank you very much, it seems to work for the piece of code you provided, however I am still unable to make it work with my SQL.

The current SQL:

```
SELECT Hca.ACCOUNT_NAME "Customer Name"
    ,hca.ACCOUNT_NUMBER "Account Number"
    ,AR_TRX_H.TRX_NUMBER "Invoice Number/Credit Memo"
    ,TO_CHAR(AR_TRX_GL.GL_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') "Accounting Date"
    ,GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9 AS "Concatenated Segments"
    ,XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR
    ,XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR
    ,
    --XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR-XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR "Balances"
    decode(XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR, NULL, 0, XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR) - decode(XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR, NULL, 0, XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR) "Balances"
    ,
FROM hz_cust_accounts hca
    ,RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL AR_TRX_H
    ,RA_CUST_TRX_LINE_GL_DIST_ALL AR_TRX_GL
    ,GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GLCC
    ,XLA_AE_HEADERS XLA_H
    ,XLA_AE_LINES XLA_L
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND HCA.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID = AR_TRX_H.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID
    AND AR_TRX_H.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
    AND AR_TRX_GL.ACCOUNT_CLASS = 'REV'
    AND AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
    AND AR_TRX_GL.EVENT_ID = XLA_H.EVENT_ID
    AND AR_TRX_GL.SET_OF_BOOKS_ID = XLA_H.LEDGER_ID
    AND XLA_H.AE_HEADER_ID = XLA_L.AE_HEADER_ID
    AND XLA_L.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
    AND GLCC.SEGMENT2 LIKE '419%'
    AND GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9 IN (
        SELECT GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9 AS "Concatenated"
        FROM hz_cust_accounts hca1
            ,RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL AR_TRX_H
            ,RA_CUST_TRX_LINE_GL_DIST_ALL AR_TRX_GL
            ,GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GLCC
            ,XLA_AE_HEADERS XLA_H
            ,XLA_AE_LINES XLA_L
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND HCA1.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID = AR_TRX_H.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID
            AND AR_TRX_H.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
            AND AR_TRX_GL.ACCOUNT_CLASS = 'REV'
            AND AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
            AND AR_TRX_GL.EVENT_ID = XLA_H.EVENT_ID
            AND AR_TRX_GL.SET_OF_BOOKS_ID = XLA_H.LEDGER_ID
            AND XLA_H.AE_HEADER_ID = XLA_L.AE_HEADER_ID
            AND XLA_L.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
            AND GLCC.SEGMENT2 LIKE '419%'
        GROUP BY GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9
        )
```

Please note that it is the Segment6 which is the value to use from the concatenated values.

After trying to add the logic you provided:

```
WITH base_data
AS (
    SELECT Hca.ACCOUNT_NAME "Customer Name"
        ,hca.ACCOUNT_NUMBER "Account Number"
        ,AR_TRX_H.TRX_NUMBER "Invoice Number/Credit Memo"
        ,TO_CHAR(AR_TRX_GL.GL_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') "Accounting Date"
        ,GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9 AS "Concatenated Segments"
        ,XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR AS CREDIT
        ,XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR AS DEBIT
        ,decode(XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR, NULL, 0, XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR) - decode(XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR, NULL, 0, XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR) "Balances"
        ,
        --Segment 6 is the value to group in order to check the amount
        GLCC.SEGMENT6 AS segment6
    FROM hz_cust_accounts hca
        ,RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL AR_TRX_H
        ,RA_CUST_TRX_LINE_GL_DIST_ALL AR_TRX_GL
        ,GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GLCC
        ,XLA_AE_HEADERS XLA_H
        ,XLA_AE_LINES XLA_L DUAL

    UNION ALL
    )
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT A.*
        ,sum(A.DEBIT + A.CREDIT) OVER (PARTITION BY A.segment6) AS extr_ID_balance
    FROM base_data A
    )
WHERE extr_ID_balance <> 0
    AND HCA.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID = AR_TRX_H.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID
    AND AR_TRX_H.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
    AND AR_TRX_GL.ACCOUNT_CLASS = 'REV'
    AND AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
    AND AR_TRX_GL.EVENT_ID = XLA_H.EVENT_ID
    AND AR_TRX_GL.SET_OF_BOOKS_ID = XLA_H.LEDGER_ID
    AND XLA_H.AE_HEADER_ID = XLA_L.AE_HEADER_ID
    AND XLA_L.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
    AND GLCC.SEGMENT2 LIKE '419%'
    AND GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9 IN (
        SELECT GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9 AS "Concatenated"
        FROM hz_cust_accounts hca1
            ,RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL AR_TRX_H
            ,RA_CUST_TRX_LINE_GL_DIST_ALL AR_TRX_GL
            ,GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GLCC
            ,XLA_AE_HEADERS XLA_H
            ,XLA_AE_LINES XLA_L
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND HCA1.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID = AR_TRX_H.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID
            AND AR_TRX_H.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
            AND AR_TRX_GL.ACCOUNT_CLASS = 'REV'
            AND AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
            AND AR_TRX_GL.EVENT_ID = XLA_H.EVENT_ID
            AND AR_TRX_GL.SET_OF_BOOKS_ID = XLA_H.LEDGER_ID
            AND XLA_H.AE_HEADER_ID = XLA_L.AE_HEADER_ID
            AND XLA_L.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
            AND GLCC.SEGMENT2 LIKE '419%'
        GROUP BY GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9
        )
```

Grateful if you could help with the above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a place where you can use analytics - see "over (partition by)" below. Since you said you knew how to pull the id from the string, that is not shown.

```
WITH base_data as
(
SELECT 1 AS ID,  '10.1.2.3' AS acct_ID, 2 as extr_ID, -10 AS CREDIT, 0 AS DEBIT, 10 AS balance FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,        '10.5.2.4',            2,              0,          10,          10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,        '22.6.1.1',            1,              0,         -15,         -15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,        '11.3.5.5',            5,             -5,           0,          -5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,        '12.3.5.6',            5,             -2,           0,          -2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,        '15.1.1.1',            1,             30,           0,          30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,        '20.16.5.1',           5,              0,           7,           7 FROM DUAL)


select * 
from 
  (
  select A.*,
     sum(A.DEBIT + A.CREDIT) over (partition by extr_id) as extr_ID_balance
  from base_data A)

where extr_ID_balance <> 0

order by 1
```

Results:

```
ID  ACCT_ID EXTR_ID CREDIT  DEBIT   BALANCE EXTR_ID_BALANCE
3   22.6.1.1    1   0       -15     -15     15
6   15.1.1.1    1   30       0       30     15
```

**Updating to address the query submitted later.**

1 - your "current query" isn't correct - you've got a dangling comma in the select list. Guessing that is a typo.

2 - I don't have your database - the "with base_data" in the example query is simply building a table from the sample data provided.

Anyway, you probably want something like this:

```
WITH base_qry
AS (
    SELECT Hca.ACCOUNT_NAME "Customer Name"
        ,hca.ACCOUNT_NUMBER "Account Number"
        ,AR_TRX_H.TRX_NUMBER "Invoice Number/Credit Memo"
        ,TO_CHAR(AR_TRX_GL.GL_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') "Accounting Date"
        ,GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9 AS "Concatenated Segments"
        ,XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR
        ,XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR
        ,
        --XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR-XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR "Balances"
        decode(XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR, NULL, 0, XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR) - decode(XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR, NULL, 0, XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR) "Balances"
        --sum debits and credits over segment_6 here
        ,sum(XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_DR + XLA_L.ACCOUNTED_CR) OVER (PARTITION BY GLCC.SEGMENT6) AS extr_ID_balance
    FROM hz_cust_accounts hca
        ,RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL AR_TRX_H
        ,RA_CUST_TRX_LINE_GL_DIST_ALL AR_TRX_GL
        ,GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GLCC
        ,XLA_AE_HEADERS XLA_H
        ,XLA_AE_LINES XLA_L
    WHERE 1 = 1
        AND HCA.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID = AR_TRX_H.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID
        AND AR_TRX_H.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
        AND AR_TRX_GL.ACCOUNT_CLASS = 'REV'
        AND AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
        AND AR_TRX_GL.EVENT_ID = XLA_H.EVENT_ID
        AND AR_TRX_GL.SET_OF_BOOKS_ID = XLA_H.LEDGER_ID
        AND XLA_H.AE_HEADER_ID = XLA_L.AE_HEADER_ID
        AND XLA_L.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
        AND GLCC.SEGMENT2 LIKE '419%'
        AND GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9 IN (
            SELECT GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9 AS "Concatenated"
            FROM hz_cust_accounts hca1
                ,RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL AR_TRX_H
                ,RA_CUST_TRX_LINE_GL_DIST_ALL AR_TRX_GL
                ,GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GLCC
                ,XLA_AE_HEADERS XLA_H
                ,XLA_AE_LINES XLA_L
            WHERE 1 = 1
                AND HCA1.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID = AR_TRX_H.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID
                AND AR_TRX_H.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
                AND AR_TRX_GL.ACCOUNT_CLASS = 'REV'
                AND AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
                AND AR_TRX_GL.EVENT_ID = XLA_H.EVENT_ID
                AND AR_TRX_GL.SET_OF_BOOKS_ID = XLA_H.LEDGER_ID
                AND XLA_H.AE_HEADER_ID = XLA_L.AE_HEADER_ID
                AND XLA_L.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = AR_TRX_GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
                AND GLCC.SEGMENT2 LIKE '419%'
            GROUP BY GLCC.SEGMENT1 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT2 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT3 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT4 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT5 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT6 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT7 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT8 || '.' || GLCC.SEGMENT9
            )
    )
SELECT *
FROM base_qry
--filter to segment 6 where debit+credit sum <> 0
WHERE extr_ID_balance <> 0
```

Didn't run this since I don't have your database - you'll probably need to debug, handle nulls, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @dandarc. It solved my issue. :)